# SCM Manager (new) user types

Tags: version-control, scmmanager

Morning SO,

This may be a really silly question - but I have recently inherited the caretaker role for SCM and have to try to cheat my way through.

I can add new users to SCM, but my team and I are all of type "ActiveDirectory" whilst new users all default to "xml"...
how can I change these types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user type depends on the authentication solution you use. The default way is the "xml" type which means a local user. You can manage them through SCM-Managers user control. Users from an external authentication provider like LDAP or Active Directory are automatically created by their first successful login attempt to SCM-Manager.

You can't and don't need to create users from an external authentication provider manually. To assign a group the a new user or to define a special permission, you can type the expected username to the free text field of the group/permission control.

Comment: thanks DaSilva, much appreciated. I have added the new member to the our group - hopefully AD will do the rest! :)